Google sign-in from OS native app (without having a website)
I'd like to develop a Windows desktop widget with Google Calendar agenda in node.js environment (e.g React Native for Windows or Electron).
Therefore, in order to be able to consume Google's Calendar API I need to implement OAuth 2.0 (Authorization flow) in order to get (and periodically refresh) access token from google authentication server.
For this purpose there is official google client library for web handling the Google Sign-in button and authentication UI flow. It means there is no problem to authenticate user from web application. Also, there is no problem to have a native Windows app that will open app's website in browser where the Google sign-in button with the client library and with redirection back to native app after user finishes sign-in process in the browser via deeplink/custom protocol.

However, I don't have any website where I could implement the Google Sign-in. Would it be possible to authenticate user without having my own website? For example by redirecting to some external google website handling the authentification UI, or some (actively maintained) 3rd party library that implements the OAuth 2.0 UI flow in native windows instead in browser?
